# Bit/data stream unknown. How to figure out?

Tags: data, digital-logic, sensor

I have taken apart a digital weight scale and on the circuit are two pins labelled 'test'. When connecting this to the soundcard of my PC I can see it is a digital signal (high/lows), but I don't know how to read/interoperate it.

Anybody knows how to do this? I'm pretty sure I once saw a free/open-source program that was able to read different kind of data protocols. Anybody know it?

Here is a recording when pressing up/down on the scale, perhaps it helps: http://lars.stonerocket.co.uk/images/electronics/weegschaal.wav

Thanks

Comment: if this is with the 2 test pins attached to the sound card input you may want to look at each test pin individually with the other end of the sound card input hooked to a gnd point on the board.  1 Pin may be the clk and 1 the data line and what you recorded may be the difference of those 2 signals.

Comment: seriously though, is there some way to actually see the waveform? it's hard to analyze with just ears.

Comment: open it in an audio editor...audacity works fine

Answer (score 4):

You could try, [xoscope](http://xoscope.sourceforge.net/), [sigrok](http://sigrok.org), [SUMP](http://www.sump.org/projects/analyzer/client/) or [gtkwave](http://gtkwave.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 3):

Looking at it with audacity (thanks, Mark!) you can see that there are definite bit cells of about 3.5msec each. The basic waveform looks like serial data at that rate, but you can see these little spikes superimposed on the basic waveform, which are probably clock signals. This would be what you'd expect if one of the lines is a clock and the other is data, and you measured across them. You could try doing what Mark suggested - find a ground point on the circuit and connect that to the sound card ground, and then feed one signal to the left channel and one to the right. But it's easy enough to separate the clock from the data visually in the sound editor.

That being said, it doesn't look like there's a whole lot of data there. There are basically two sequences, these being a simple ..10101010.., and a slightly more complicated one that looks like '01101001' repeated over and over. But these are just the raw bits. It could be something like an NRZ scheme, where '01' means 0 and '10' means 1. Or the other way round. But no matter how you slice it, there just doesn't seem to be much complexity in there.

Comment: the wave form actually makes sense if one line is the clk and one the data.  The section with "10101010" would be created if the data line was held low (or high) but the clock was running.  The section with "01101001" could be created by the actual data being transmitted combined with the clock still running.  It still looks like an odd standard as that would mean the clock is running when no data is being transmitted so its definitely not I2C, i guess it could be SPI but it would be a weird implementation.

Comment: @Mark: i think i see what you mean, you think the clock is 50% duty cycle with a period of about 7msec, toggling constantly. what i'm thinking, though, is that the clock is that little glitchy thing you see about 0.25ms after every major level change. It's also there in between bit cells with adjacent 0's or adjacent 1's as well. But even if it's the 50% d.c. thing, you can XOR that out and it still isn't a very complex signal. I'm going to go squint at it some more, maybe there are occasional deviations from the pattern.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Recording the pins separate is good idea.

There are sometimes different lengths of deviation. For example, @3,4 there is a 4 clock cycles high. Or @4,3 there is a 3 clock cycles high.

I could also record again, but than from the start, so also the booting part will be recorded.

Is there perhaps a program that I can feed this audio-file and I can try different data protocols?

Comment: well, if you post the data from each pin we can probably tell you the protocol (i think its just SPI).  

Thats really only the first 25% of the battle.  After you know that you need to look at what data its transmitting and figure out what it is/does/means.  The best way to do that is with a SPI to USB converter so you can monitor the bus on a PC and inject data into it.

This can be done with a few different tools such as the bus pirate flyguy mentioned or several other units, http://www.diolan.com/i2c/u2c12.html is my favorite.

Answer (score 2):

Just shooting in the dark but a two pin interface for something like a scale is probably a serial signal.  My first try would be 9600 baud with 3.3v levels. If that did not work then I would try different baud rates.

Answer (score 2):

If it is any kind of standard protocol, it sounds like you might be able to hook up a [Bus Pirate](http://code.google.com/p/the-bus-pirate/) to it and try different protocols.

Comment: hm... this seems like a pretty cool little board, have you actually used it?